# PHP Onclick event that adds 1 to a database (SQL)

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

Basically, what I am trying to accomplish is being able for the users to click a button on my html site and it adds a 1 to their account balance. How would I do this? I think it would be like this:

```
$sql = "UPDATE balance SET +1 WHERE id=session";
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you please post code that you have tried so far?

Comment: `UPDATE balance SET columnname = columnname + 1 WHERE id = $userid`

Comment: PHP doesn't listen clicks, also you are trying wrong query which again is not PHP. please check & correct your question again.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql= "UPDATE balance SET columnname = columnname + 1 WHERE id = {$SESION['userid']}";
```

Its advisable to use PDO and parameterized queries